# React Native: showing/hiding the element on click

Tags: reactjs

This might be a double of some question, but I couldn't find the answer to the specific question that I have. I have the following code:

import React, { Component } from 'react'

```
class FAQContent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false,
        };
        this.toggleBox = this.toggleBox.bind(this);
    }

    toggleBox() {
        const { opened } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            opened: !opened,
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="question">
                    <div className="question-title" onClick={this.toggleBox}>
                        Title 1
                </div>
                    {this.state.opened && (
                        <div class="answer">
                        Content 1
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="question">
                    <div className="question-title" onClick={this.toggleBox}>
                        Title 2
            </div>
                    {this.state.opened && (
                        <div class="answer">
                        Content 2
                </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FAQContent
```

This renders 2 question titles. However, when I click on any of the questions, the state change is triggered for all the questions. What is the most efficient way of showing the specific answer of the question  without showing the rest of the components?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    openedPost: "",
    posts: [
      { question: "Question 1", id: 0, user: "lenny" },
      { question: "Question 2", id: 1, user: "benny" },
      { question: "Question 3", id: 2, user: "jenny" }
    ]
  };
  showPost = id => {
    this.setState({ openedPost: id });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                <Posts showPost={this.showPost} posts={this.state.posts} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={`/posts/${this.state.openedPost}`}
              render={() => (
                <SinglePost
                  openedPost={this.state.openedPost}
                  showPost={this.showPost}
                  posts={this.state.posts}
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Posts extends Component {
  onClick = id => {
    this.props.showPost(id);
  };
  render() {
    const { posts, showPost } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {posts.map(item => (
          <div onClick={() => this.onClick(item.id)}>
            <Link to={`/posts/${item.id}`}>{item.question} </Link>{" "}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SinglePost extends Component {
  render() {
    const { posts, openedPost } = this.props;
    const filtered = posts.filter(item => item.id === openedPost);
    return (
      <div>
        {filtered.map(item => (
          <div>
            {" "}
            QUESTION:{item.question} ID:{item.id}{" "}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7yzvzmmxo)

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is this ES6 compatible? Cause I'm getting errors.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the right one but I can't make it work. Could you please adjust it according to the example I gave?

Comment: In React Native you cant use a div or any other HTML tag. Use <View>, <Text> etc. Read more - https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis

Answer (score 0):

You are using a same state to control different parts. How about you make a new question component and let it to manage its own state and just use the question component in the FAQContent component.

Question component:

```
export default class Question extends Component {
  state = { opened: false };

  toggleBox = () => this.setState(state => ({ opened: !state.opened }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="question">
         <div className="question-title" onClick={this.toggleBox}>
             {this.props.title}
         </div>
         {this.state.opened && (
            <div class="answer">
               {this.props.content}
            </div>
          )}
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

FAQContent Component:

```
const FAQContent = () => (
  <div>
    <Question title="title 1" content="content 1" />
    <Question title="title 2" content="content 2" />
  </div>
);
export default FAQContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But all my answers contain images and long texts. How to pass that effectively as a prop?

Comment: I am not sure what your data source looks like. But it usually can do like: data.map(element => <Question title={element.title} image={element.image} content={element.content} />);

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how to map several paragraphs to props. Sorry, I'm new in React.

Comment: Could you please show an example of your data source?

Comment: It's a template consisted of a span title with max 250 characters and a body with 3 paragraphs of text max 1500 characters.